# write Website Content into XML File in JAVA

Tags: java, xml, web-content

is it possible to get all website content into XML file ?
means if i provided Website URL then it will  get all website Content into XML file using JAVA.

if i give URL of this page then all content of this page will be in XML file.

Comment: Yes. If this is an unsatisfying answer, please take the time to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - thanks!

Comment: What do you mean with "Website URL to XML file" ? In what way exactly do you want to put the website content in to the XML file, could you expand a bit and describe your problem ?

Comment: @JonasCz means that if i give this page URL http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36546808/write-website-content-into-xml-file-in-java?noredirect=1#comment60694415_36546808 then all data of this page will be download into XML file.

Answer (score 0):

A very simplified approach do download a website (only static content) could be

```
// read the website from this URL
URL urlIn = new URL("http://www.example.com/index.html");
// save the content as file "/tmp/example.out"
Path pathOut = Paths.get("/tmp/example.out");
// read and write the data
Files.copy(urlIn.openStream(), pathOut, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

Comment: @SagarPatel In that case you should answer to the already given comments and provide an example. **1)** How does the website look like you want to download. **2)** How should the XML look like for this example HTML page. Without this information it's nearly impossible to guess what you want to achieve.

Comment: 1). Websites is any knd of its not fixed .
2). also XML format is not fixed it will be depend on Website.

like if give URL of Stackoverflow.com then My xml will be in paired of Question and Answer.

Comment: @SagarPatel So you expect some `artificial intelligence` which knows how to separate the different webpages content. e.g. for `stackoverflow.com` into `request` and `answers`, and for `some.music.shop` into `CD name` and `tracks`? I believe this is not possible. Expect the webpages provide some [RDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Description_Framework) data.

Comment: yes you exactly right... i need data as you described format.

Comment: @SagarPatel For StackOverflow you might have a look here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146481/stack-overflow-api-for-java and https://api.stackexchange.com/. For any other page you have to check for other solutions.